# colResizable row display:none; and the custom anchors relating to the row to have a display:none;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a bit stuck and was wondering if anyone could please help me? I am developing a website that has colResizable JQuery plugin incorporated into it. The plugin is all good and brilliant -its just that I need to have a button that once selected makes the middle row of the colResizable table have a display of none with the custom anchors (relating only to that table row) also having a display of none. And once the button is selected, it is replaced with a button that has 'show', then once that is selected the middle row of the colResizable table appears and the custom anchors of that row also appear. Here is the code that I have so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>colResizable demo</title>  

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />  
  <script  src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script  src="js/colResizable-1.5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){ 

  var onTableCreated = function(){
   $("#updatePanelSample").colResizable({
    liveDrag:true, 
    gripInnerHtml:"<div class='grip'></div>", 
    draggingClass:"dragging", 
    postbackSafe:true,
    fixed:false,
    partialRefresh:true,
   }); 
  }

  var fakePostback = function(){
   $("#updatePanel").html('<img src="img/loading.gif"/>');
   setTimeout(function(){
    $("#updatePanel").html('<table id="updatePanelSample" width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> <tbody><tr> <th>header</th><th>header</th><th>header</th> </tr> <tr> <td class="left">cell</td><td>cell</td><td class="right">cell</td> </tr> <tr> <td class="left">cell</td><td>cell</td><td class="right">cell</td> </tr> <tr> <td class="left bottom">cell</td><td class="bottom">cell</td><td class="bottom right">cell</td> </tr> </tbody></table>');
    onPostbackOver();
    }, 700);
  };
  
  var onPostbackOver = function(){
   onTableCreated();
  };
  
  $("#postback").click(fakePostback);
  onTableCreated();
  
  });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  
 function hide_cells(){
 
  document.getElementById("get_cells").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("get_cells2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("get_cells3").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("get_cells4").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("change_to_show").innerHTML = "<button onClick='show_cells()' >Show</button >";
 
 }
 
 function show_cells(){
 
  document.getElementById("get_cells").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("get_cells2").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("get_cells3").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("get_cells4").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("change_to_show").innerHTML = "<button onClick='hide_cells()' >Hide</button >";
 
 }
  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="center" >
 
   <br/><br/>
      
  <div id="change_to_show"><button onClick="hide_cells()" >Hide</button ></div>
    
  <div id="updatePanel">   
    <table id="updatePanelSample"  width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
     <th>header</th><th id="get_cells">header2</th><th>header3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="left">cell</td><td id="get_cells2">cell</td><td class="right">cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="left">cell</td><td id="get_cells3">cell</td><td class="right">cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="left bottom">cell</td><td id="get_cells4" class="bottom">cell</td><td class="bottom right">cell</td>
    </tr>                 
   </table>
  </div>
  
  <br/>
  
  
  <br/><br/>

 </div> 
  

 
  
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here is the link to the colResizable website: http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/

Thanks - any help is highly appreciated!

**Updates** - I have included some additional information below in order to illustrate what I mean more clearly:

Here is the table and the button that I am working with:

[image]

Here is what I mean by the custom anchor:

[image]

Here is what happens when I click the 'hide' button that has the 'hide_cell()' function incorporated into it via an onClick:

[image]

Notice that even though the the middle column ('header2') disappeared, the custom anchor relating to that column remains, and the other anchor is not in the correct position.

I was wondering if anyone could please help with this problem I am facing? Thanks :) Here's the link to the colResizable plugin site:http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/

Answer (score 0):

Cells are not `inline` displayed. You must to change to `table-cell`:

```
  document.getElementById("get_cells4").style.display = "table-cell";
```

There are this values for display in tables:

`table` > applied to `<table>` tag

`table-row` > applied to `<tr>` tag

`table-cell` > applied to `<td>` tag

Learn more:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help @Marcos :) This works good, but the only other problem that I am facing is that the colResizable plugin has anchors that allow the user to resize the cells. Once the row is display:none; the anchors that relate to that row are still present. Whereas I want just the anchor(s) that relate to that cell to also have a display of none without affect the other rows and their anchors. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Any suggestions @Marcos Pérez Gude? Thanks for the initial response btw :)

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle.com with your code and the plugin? It's better to help you

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out - I needed to find the child [1] of the JCLRgrip. Then change it via the JavaScript to have a display of none, as illustrated below:

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function hide_cells(){

  document.getElementById("get_cells").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("get_cells2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("get_cells3").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("get_cells4").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("change_to_show").innerHTML = "<button onClick='show_cells()' >Show</button >";
  document.getElementsByClassName("JCLRgrip")[1].style.display = "none";
  document.getElementsByClassName("JCLRgrip")[2].style.display = "none";
 
 }
 
 function show_cells(){
 
  document.getElementById("get_cells").style.display = "table-cell";
  document.getElementById("get_cells2").style.display = "table-cell";
  document.getElementById("get_cells3").style.display = "table-cell";
  document.getElementById("get_cells4").style.display = "table-cell";
  document.getElementById("change_to_show").innerHTML = "<button onClick='hide_cells()' >Hide</button >";
 
 }
  
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

before any DOM manipulation you have to call colresizable with the param "disable" set to true.

**disable:** [type: boolean] [default: false] [version: 1.0]
When set to true it aims to remove all previously added enhancements such as events and additional DOM elements assigned by this plugin to a single or collection of tables. It is required to disable a previously colResized table prior its removal from the document object tree using JavaScript, and also before any DOM manipulations to an already colResized table such as adding columns, rows, etc.

so your code will be something like this

```
var onHideColumn = function(){

     $("#updatePanelSample").colResizable({disable:true}); //disable colresizable
     hide_cells();  //remove columns, or whatever
     $("#updatePanelSample").colResizable();  //enable it again

}
```

There is a sample included in the version released for colResizable 1.6, you can download it from [github](https://github.com/alvaro-prieto/colResizable) or from the [official website](http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/)